# NSusbtitute incorrectly calculates the number of calls on a mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

```
public class Device
{
    private readonly IProtocol _protocol;

    public Device(IProtocol protocol)
    {
        _protocol = protocol;
    }

    public bool Connect(string port)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (_protocol.Connect(port))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
public interface IProtocol
{
     bool Connect(string port);
}

    [Test]
    public void Connect_FailedThrice_ThreeTries()
    {
        IProtocol provider = Substitute.For<IProtocol>();
        provider.Connect(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(false);

        var sut = new Device(provider);
        sut.Connect(Arg.Any<string>());

        provider.Received(3).Connect(Arg.Any<string>());
    }
```

The result of running a unit test - an error saying that the Connect method was called twice, not thrice. Debugging shows that the method is called thrice.

Answer (score 2):

[NSubstitute documentation](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/) says

> Using Arg.Is or Arg.Any without a call to .Returns or Received() can cause your tests to behave in unexpected ways. See How NOT to use argument matchers for more information.

Try to pass in `sut.Connect` method any string

```
[TestMethod]
public void Connect_FailedThrice_ThreeTries()
{
     IProtocol provider = Substitute.For<IProtocol>();
     provider.Connect(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(false);

     var sut = new Device(provider);
     sut.Connect("hello");

     provider.Received(3).Connect(Arg.Any<string>());
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. Hmm... seems like it's very inconsistent from the APIs perspective of NSubstitute. Such behavior is far from being obvious.

Comment: @EngineerSpock ok, i found out :)